# Can I suspend jquery ready event until my script execution is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problem, I have to do some regex replacement to document.innerHTML on page load. but all jquery plugins and jquery method cannot detect body's child elements, I want to rescan document.body object after my regex replace operation. though Not a resonable solution, I did this with jquery as

```
$("body").html($("body").html());
```

after body.innerHTML replacement,
It works, jquery method can detect newly changed elements, but it also effect scripts within body tag causing double triggering plugins and requesting script file to server again. I want jquery to detect modified body's element. To do so, can I suspend $(document).ready() event till body's content is updated or is there other technique to reload document.body object. Please don't refer to `delegate()` `on()` and `live()` methods. I know usage of these methods, I don't want to use this approache, I just want jquery to detect modified elements in body, Please help me, thanks alot.

Comment: Have you tried [holdReady()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/)?

Comment: `preg_replace`.. isn't that a `php` function?

Comment: sorry, I mean javascript regex string replacement.

Comment: thanks for your suggection @Frédéric Hamidi, but jquery does not detect replaced elements